# set ng-model to property of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have select-box in my view where you can select a worker.

```
<select ng-model="search.wrk_worker_id">
    <option ng-repeat="w in workers.message">{{w.wrk_forename}}</option>
</select>
```

`w` has following properties:

- wrk_worker_id
- wrk_forename
- wrk_surname

and so on!

is it possible to bind `search.wrk_worker_id` to `w.wrk_worker_id`, but still show `w.wrk_forename` in the select box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you specify a value property on your option this is the value that will bind to search.wrk_worker_id after you select the option in the selectbox:

```
<select ng-model="search.wrk_worker_id">
   <option ng-repeat="w in workers.message" value={{w.wrk_worker_id}}>{{w.wrk_forename}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved the day ! :)